# yarn run dev でのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ubuntu

**前提・実現したいこと**
GitBushを用いて環境構築を行っています。
実現したいことはモックの起動です。
その前段階でデータベースを作成したいのですが、上手くいっておらず今回のコマンドを入力いたしました。
プログラミング初心者の学生ですので、頂いた回答に対して追加の質問で返させていただくことがあるかもしれません。
何卒ご了承ください。

こちら自分の環境です。
Windows10
rbenv 2.7.1
Ubuntu 20.04

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**完了させたいコマンド**

```
yarn run dev
```

**試したこと**

・ibyamlのインストール
・Rubyのアンインストールとインストール

**補足情報**
Rubyのインストールの際に以下のメッセージが表示されていたのですが、

```
Installing ruby-2.7.1...
Installed ruby-2.7.1 to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1
```

`ruby --version` を行うと以下のように表示されており、バージョンが違うことも気になっています。

```
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/297261

Comment: "環境構築している" とありますが、何の環境なのかが曖昧です。 / rbenv を利用しているなら適切な設定を行わないと OS 標準の Ruby を参照したままになります。(バージョン番号が意図した通りに表示されないのはこのためでしょう) / 参考: [rbenv を利用した Ruby 環境の構築](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/build-ruby-environment-by-rbenv/)